# How to run heroku commands from a script without entering credentials manually

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

How do I run heroku commands without logging in first?

I've already tried putting the .netrc file in ~, but that didn't work.  Is there some environmental variable or command line thing I can use to let me start running my heroku stuff without requiring manual intervention?

We've got a couple one-off heroku workers where we're trying to use nagios to see if they're up and accepting commands.

If I run this script after I've logged into heroku on this machine as the correct user manually, it works.  If I haven't, it doesn't.  And since we're trying to pull the perfect world of completely automagic instance setup and configuration, heroku is becoming an issue.

As far as I can tell (keeping in mind that I'm NOT the heroku guy and our heroku guy isn't terribly sure himself), setting the netrc file should work, but it just keeps getting wiped out by heroku.  I gotta believe they have support for this.

Script is:

```
# Check for two or more workers up for each of our heroku apps. 

HEROKU_APPS=$(heroku apps | grep -v '^=') 

exit_status=0 

for app in $HEROKU_APPS; do 
    workers_up=$(heroku ps --app=$app | grep -c 'web\.[12]: up') 
    if [ 1 -eq $workers_up ]; then 
        exit_status=1 
    elif [ 0 -eq $workers_up ]; then 
        exit_status=2 
        exit $exit_status 
    fi 
done 

exit $exit_status
```

/Also, I admit that it's possible that we're being idiots by attempting to hack nagios into checking if heroku is up.  Is there a better (free, simple) solution for this?

Comment: Are you running that script as the same user account you normally use for Heroku commands?  I use the following simple script and it just worked.   #!/bin/sh

heroku create $*

Comment: Can you provide the script you are trying to run?  Perhaps as a Github Gist?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `expect` which suits your needs, for example the following:

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh me@host; expect assword; send "password\n"; interact'
```

launches `ssh` and waits for it to print `assword` in the console, at which point it will send the string `password` to it. So you just have to understand what is getting printed when `heroku` asks you for credentials.